# Reindexing SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to re-index SQL database. I am completely new to it.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.2500.

Can some one suggest the best way to do this. Do we have any free tools for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking a more specific question. The site isn't generally good for "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas" questions.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.2500 DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the DBMS itself. Possibly the most portable solution is to simply drop the index and then re-create it (making sure that nobody inserts a record in the table that violates the index between the two operations of course).

However, the *first* question I'd be asking myself is *why* you think this is necessary. It seems unlikely that any change outside the DB would require re-indexing of *current* indexes, although it may be that your requirement is to add new (or delete old) indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are making some configuration in our application. It need content re-indexing.

Comment: @User222, that seems strange. I can see that something outside the DB may require _new_ indexes to be set up but not anything that would simply require re-indexing. Still, I'll defer to your expertise there.

Answer (score 2):

What DBMS are you on? This is for SQL Server. If you are using SQL server you can use management studio, and drill down on a table -> indexes. Then right click each index and do rebuild, or create a stored proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ReindexAll]

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"

    EXEC sp_updatestats

END
```